# Who is responsible for decision?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

If you are responsible for implementing a customized and central portal for a customer, about 1000 employee in the organization, and my question is.

Who is the actually the buyer from the customer's side? Is it IT-chief or many manager from different unit in order to make a final decision?

Comment: This isn't really a SharePoint question, and to be honest not much of a question at all.  Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Who pays for the project? This will be the decision maker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an organization of 1000 employees, the desicion maker and sponsor of a SharePoint project is most likely the Chief Information Officer (CIO) and/or Chief Communication Officer (COO). It depends on whether the SharePoint project is an Intranet only or an External website or both.

If the project involves a high degree of customization (= many hours = expensive project) the CIO/COO probably are running a board with several other competences to control the project. In any case there is a Project Manager assigned from the customer who reports to the board/sponsors and who are your main contact.

In your case, try to find out who is the Project Manager and ask her/him of the customer organization in this project.